# Concurrent Thread-Safe List access and modification

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety

What I want to be able to do is to access a `List` on multiple threads. This is thread safe, so I can just do it without worries. The only problem is that occasionally, I must modify the `List`. So, I want to prevent other threads from using the `List` only when it is being modified.

This is what I'm thinking, is there a better way?

```
volatile bool isReading = false;
volatile bool isWriting = false;
object o = new object();
public void StartRead()
{
    lock (o)
    {
        while (isWriting || isReading) ;
        isReading = true;
    }
}
public void StopRead()
{
    isReading = false;
}
public void StartWrite()
{
    lock (o)
    {
        while (isReading) ;
        isWriting = true;
    }
}
public void StopWrite()
{
    isWriting = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.  This will let you have many readers at the same time, but only lock it when you have a writer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

This really depends on just how much contention there is for the lock though.  In low-contention situations, a `lock` will perform similarly to the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` - reference [When is ReaderWriterLockSlim better than a simple lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217398/when-is-readerwriterlockslim-better-than-a-simple-lock).

There's many possible solutions to this question, depending on a lot of specifics about how it's being used.  But, in the simplistic "taken at face value" case, a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is a decent solution.  If it doesn't work for you after profiling performance, then other solutions may be needed that accommodate your specific usage scenarios.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize there was so much in System.Threading.