# How to limit the memory used by ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#

I use a `ConcurrentDictionary<String, String>` to store a big amount of data (4 500 000 entries), and I dont want to use extra memory, so I fixed the capacity at the beginning. But the dictionary grow automatically before reaching the specified capacity.

I wrote a little portion of code to show the matter with only 500 items, I do reflection on the private buckets array because I didn't find a public property giving the real capacity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MemoryUsage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CapacityTest();
        }
        private static void CapacityTest()
        {
            int capacity = 500;
            ConcurrentDictionary<String, String> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(Environment.ProcessorCount, capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} buckets", GetBucketCount(dict));
            for (int index = 0; index < capacity; index++)
                dict.AddOrUpdate(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), (key, value) => value);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} buckets", GetBucketCount(dict));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static int GetBucketCount(ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dict)
        {
            object tables = dict.GetType().GetField("m_tables", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(dict); // "_tables" with .NET Core, "m_tables" with .NET Framework
            object buckets = tables.GetType().GetField("m_buckets", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(tables); // "_buckets" with .NET Core, "m_buckets" with .NET Framework
            return ((Array)buckets).Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
500 buckets at the beginning
1003 buckets at the end
```

I expected `500 buckets at the end`. Do you know a way to avoid allocating extra memory since I know the number of items at the beginning?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303884/concurrentdictionary-with-limit

Comment: I am not aware of this. I think you can use caching classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications

Comment: This seems to have to do with the distribution of the values. I tried your code with a set of integers (0-7) with processor count = 8. Then there are just 8 buckets.

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` has to allow for some slack to allow lock-free operation with multiple threads. If you use `1` or `2` instead of `Environment.ProcessorCount`, you'll get the minimum buckets (on my system, at least). Obviously, this is not exactly something you can count on, as it also depends on your value distribution.

Comment: You're right @JeroenMostert, with 1 instead of `Environment.ProcessorCount`, the capacity is respected. But I guess it will downgrade the performance in multithreaded environment, I have to check.

Comment: If you know the initial capacity because you're going to initialize it from one single source, you can also try using the constructor overload that takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<...>>` (you may need to write an iterator method for this). In my tests, this produces a dictionary with an initial bucket size larger than the actual capacity, but not twice as large.

Comment: Finally, I simply lowered the concurrencyLevel to 1 in production as a quick fix => no more OutOfMemoryException for a while. I didn't measure it, but it's probably slower.
Now I have to choose between Dictionary<A,B> wrapper with read/write lock mechanism or migrating huge operations to the database (probably the best choice).

Answer (score 1):

It's initial capacity not just capacity. So you can't limit it.

Don't reinvent the wheel, just use [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8). It automatically deletes items in case of lack of memory. If you really want to control memory use [MemoryCache.CacheMemoryLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.cachememorylimit?view=netframework-4.8) for instance.

Comment: There may be some use cases where replacing a `ConcurrentDictionary` with a `MemoryCache` is appropriate, but certainly not all. In particular, we may actually need all of those keys all of the time! Also, `MemoryCache` is strictly worse in terms of memory use and concurrent performance (assuming the same capacity), as internally it wraps around a good old fashioned non-generic `Hashtable` with a good old fashioned lock.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I added wrong links to my answer. I mean this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory MemoryCache from this package uses `ConcurrentDictionary` internally - https://github.com/aspnet/caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs

Comment: Sure, but then that doesn't solve the original problem at all, as while you can specify a size limit for that, it runs into the same capacity problem (obviously, as it uses `ConcurrentDictionary` under the covers). That is, even if you know in advance you have X items, you can't make `MemoryCache` consume memory only for X items. This is true even if you use the size limit for this, as that only limits item count, not capacity.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have to do with the distribution of the values (for either optimization of the locking mechanism or characteristics of the used tree structure). I tried your code with a set of integers (0-7) with processor count = 8. Then there are just 8 buckets.

```
dict.AddOrUpdate(index, index, (key, value) => value);
```

But when multiplying the key by 2, there are 17 buckets after attempt 5 out of 8.